# Can AWS Codepipeline track multiple repositories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have 2 Github repositories:

```
PandaService
PandaServiceDataAccessLayer
```

`PandaService` is depended on `PandaServiceDataAccessLayer`. I can build a fat jar locally with Gradle composite build as mentioned here: [How to build a fat jar with multi-project and Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72245259/how-to-build-a-fat-jar-with-multi-project-and-gradle/72343108)

Now I want to make AWS Codepipeline track both github repositories, so that once I push new change to either repository, AWS Codepipeline will build a new fatJar for the service.

Is it possible to do it? If not, any suggestions on how to get multi-projects fat jar integrated with AWS Codepipeline?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842611/aws-codepipeline-track-multiple-repositories-as-a-single-source

Comment: I think this can be solved with https://blog.marcnuri.com/triggering-github-actions-across-different-repositories. I will try and comment back later, as I have other issues to sort out at this moment